# Rudin Real and Complex Analysis, How Theorem 7.10 leads to a generalization of Theorem 7.8?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

[image]

Here $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^k$. After Theorem 7.10, Rudin says that Theorem 7.10 leads to a correspondingly stronger form of Theorem 7.8, but I can't see why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is stronger than Theorem 7. 8 because for any sequence $(r_i) \to 0$ $B(x,r_i)$ shrinks to $x$ nicely. [Take $\alpha =1$ in the definition].

Comment: What you wrote is a portion of the proof of Theorem 7.10. What is the stronger form of Theorem 7.8 that Rudin means? I can't see what it is.

Comment: @Quadr I have edited the answer.

Comment: Oh I see. Theorem 7.10 generalizes the statement $D\mu=f$ $m$-a.e. in Theorem 7.8. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.